# How do I create a Team Leader/Group Leader in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm new(this is my first project) to web development. I'm creating an internal data management for the company i work for. We have different departments(like r&d, product development, etc) which I have instantiated as objects via Django admin. I have created employees as normal Users in django admin. I would like to know how I can create a model/anything which can tell me the department manager.

Answer (score 0):

Django auth user has reference to the group model. So you can create a group called Teamleader in group table(django admin) and while creating a user link the user to the group desired for his role